# Can recipients for a Mailchimp campaign be passed as a list of email addresses?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Is it possible to create a Mailchimp campaign via the API and pass the recipients as a list of email address rather than using the segmenting options?

The segmenting options seem a bit too limited for what I want to do and it would be easier if I could just send a list of addresses to add to a campaign, you can do this via the front end but can't see similar functionality in the API

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be limited number of options here, you will have to go for one or another:

1. Mandrill (MailChimp's transactional API)
2. Or deal with the segmentation for selection of contacts/members

Maybe if you post the exact problem you are trying to solve, I can offer some workaround.